# Omit a mouse click as part of keyup function

Tags: jquery, function

I have a function that is triggered by a keyup command in a text input box, and I'd like to prevent the initial focus on the box (either by mouse click or touch) from triggering the function, so it only starts to work when someone starts typing in the box. I've stripped all the code back to the below:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
            var inputString = $("#searchInput").val();
            $("#autoSearchButton a").attr("href", inputString);
            });
        });
```

Is there a way of the function only triggering when someone is actually entering characters?

Comment: Since you're only catching `keyup` event on the `#searchInput` element, `keyup` events when it or its descendants are focused should be the only thing triggering that function. The issue is likely to be elsewhere.

Comment: I am not sure how is a mouse click triggering keyup event? You probably should be using 'input' event since person can paste content into a textbox without typing.

Comment: Please explain what you're actually building, what is that you need, the use-case, and explain further your problem. Most importantly, [edit] to create a [mcve].

Comment: When you click on an `<input>` Element (is that what you have?) there's obviously no `"key"` Event triggering by default.